# Running Flask at startup as a Service in Windows won't work in background

Tags: powershell, automation, background-process

Before explaining what my problem is, please know that I have looked up for solutions on similar topics but none of them seems to work nor even to corresponds to my problem.

## What I am trying to do:

I have this python code on multiple files that I run with flask with the following command:

```
python -m flask run --host=0.0.0.0
```

So far, **everything works**, but I would like this code to **automatically run everytime the computer boots**. In the future this will be used on  mini PCs without any graphical interface nor human intervention.

Since I need to do some configuration checks before running the web server, I've created a powershell script that ends with Flask running (using the previous command).

So far, **everything works too**. Now we're coming to the **problem**:
I'd like this script to run when I boot the machine. Specificity: Every things needs to work with **Administrator privileges**, on the local system without any interaction.

I've tried *scheduled tasks* but Flask won't run even if the rest of the script works (like creating folders or other things)

Ok, it's not a big deal I have other ways to do it, so I've created a Windows Service in C# to run the Script at startup on the local system.

**The script works**, I've checked the privileges too, everything's fine but arriving at the flask command line that is supposed to make it run, nothing works.

It's the same thing if I run flask using "pythonw" which is supposed to run python as a background process.

## **What the problem seems to be:**

Well, as long as I run flask and I have either a command prompt or a powershell terminal, everything works greats. But if in a way or another I run the script as a background process, it won't work.

Normally it would take around 30 seconds for Flask to start-up. Here if I try to create a folder right after flask ended starting up (as a test) I can see the folder is created almost instantly, which means the process is immediately killed.

The problem doesn't seem to come from the service itself but really Windows that kills the process I don't know why

I'm running out of idea so if you guys have anything that I could try it would really help me.